# Bootstrap: table border-radius strange behaviour

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with tables border-radius that changes depending on how many lines are in the table. On the pictures below, you can see that the two bottom corners of the table follow the Bootstrap CSS border-radius property. If I remove certain lines manually, the corners do not follow the property anymore...

I include the HTML and CSS codes underneath.

[image]

[image]

**Code :**

First picture HTML:

```
    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>Indicateurs<span class="sup"> 1</span>  : <span>Eaux usées</span></div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class='table table-striped' id='table-to-result-ass-indic'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>Matériau</th>                                           <td>97.9 %</td>     <td>15452 m</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Diamètre</th>                                           <td>99.1 %</td>     <td>15641 m</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Matériau et diamètre</th>                               <td>99.1 %</td>     <td>15641 m</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Période de pose<span class="sup"> 2</span></th>         <td>35.5 %</td>     <td>5603 m</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Altimétrie<span class="sup"> 3</span></th>              <td>4.5 %</td>      <td>710 m</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Nombre de branchements<span class="sup"> 4</span></th>  <td>18.5 %</td>     <td>190.467 km</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Classe A<span class="sup"> 5</span></th>                <td>4.8 %</td>      <td>49.418 km</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Classe B<span class="sup"> 5</span></th>                <td>0 %</td>        <td>0 km</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Classe C<span class="sup"> 5</span></th>                <td>93.3 %</td>     <td>960.570 km</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Classe non-renseignée<span class="sup"> 5</span></th>   <td>1.9 %</td>      <td>19.561 km</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Linéaire total</th>                                     <td>100 %</td>      <td>1029.550 km</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

First picture CSS:

[image]

Second picture HTML:

```
    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>Indicateurs<span class="sup"> 1</span>  : <span>Eaux usées</span></div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class='table table-striped' id='table-to-result-ass-indic'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th>Matériau</th>                   <td>97.9 %</td>     <td>15452 m</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Diamètre</th>                   <td>99.1 %</td>     <td>15641 m</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Matériau et diamètre</th>       <td>99.1 %</td>     <td>15641 m</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Classe A</th>                   <td>4.8 %</td>      <td>49.418 km</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Classe B</th>                   <td>0 %</td>        <td>0 km</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Classe C</th>                   <td>93.3 %</td>     <td>960.570 km</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Classe non-renseignée</th>      <td>1.9 %</td>      <td>19.561 km</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Linéaire total</th>             <td>100 %</td>      <td>1029.550 km</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Second picture CSS:

[image]

Comment: Which properties did you remove? Can you include the CSS?

Comment: please provide your css

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited my post and added the CSS from Firebug that showes Bootstrap and non-Bootstrap properties.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
.table-striped tbody tr:last-child td
{
     border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem (same as before)... It looks like a CSS conflict but I can't find where it comes from (see Firebug CSS screenshots added in my post).

Comment: not sure , but i think white rows have more height than grays,so when a gray row is last row it comes out of panel
if this be the problem you should give the last row or td's of last row a border radius : 
border-radius:0px 0px 4px 4px !important;  
add this to your css and let me know what happened @wiltomap

Comment: Good idea. I have added the following CSS but **without success** : `.table td:last-child {border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px !important;}`. Also tried with `.table tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `.panel` has *20px bottom margin*. That's why bottom border-radius is hidden or not visible.
Just remove

```
.panel{
margin-bottom:20px;
}
```